# why is oracle ignoring scale in number datatype

Tags: oracle, numbers

select cast(2457431.6443981482 as number(25,13)) from dual

results are 2457431.64

I thought had significant of 38 digits, is there a max scale of digits to right of decimal, need to store above number in table as is without rounding

Comment: Which client are you running that in? Looks like whatever it is is set to only show two decimal places - it's a client issue though, not an Oracle one, and doesn't affect how the value would be stored. You can see that with `select to_char(cast(2457431.6443981482 as number(25,13)), '9999999.9999999')` which will bypass the client number formatting.

Comment: When I execute `SELECT TO_CHAR(2457431.6443981482, '0000000000000000000000000.0000000000000') FROM DUAL` in PL/SQL Developer I get `0000000000000000002457431.6443981482000`. The number you've given is being processed with all its precision and scale preserved, so as @AlexPoole points out this is very likely a client formatting issue.